# How can I change MATLAB's default formatting?

Tags: matlab, number-formatting

Opening a new MATLAB R2022a session, I notice the default formatting set to `shortG`, where I expected it to be just `short`. How can I change the default back to `short`?

```
>> fmt = format

fmt = 

  DisplayFormatOptions with properties:

    NumericFormat: "shortG"
      LineSpacing: "loose"
```

Comment: In R2017b at least you can change that in Preferences: MATLAB: Command Window: Numeric format

Comment: Thanks @LuisMendo, that has fixed the problem. It seems that setting was changed by mistake or I'm not sure how exactly that was changed. Can you please post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Sure, I just posted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change that in `Preferences` → `MATLAB` → `Command Window` → `Numeric format`:

[image]